# Case statement int to string conversion

Tags: sql, db2, case, type-conversion

I'm using a db2 database.  I need a case statement that will convert every row with "-1" to "N/A".  The remainder of the rows must be formatted to a percentage.  My query is below:

```
 SELECT
 case when sopm.TARGET_VALUE = '-1000'
        then   'N/A'
        ELSE sopm.TARGET_VALUE
        END as TARGET_VALUE
 FROM SUMMARY_PERFORMANCE_METRIC sopm
```

the data is as follows

```
3.5000  
 0.8000  
 0.8500  
 0.8000  
 0.2000  
 0.0500  
 -1.0000  
 -1.0000  
 0.9500  
 0.9000  
 0.4000  
 -1.0000
```

the above script does not produce an error but does not give me the correct results either.

desired output:

```
3.5
 80%
 85%
 80%
 20%
 5%
 N/A
 N/A
 95%
 90%
 40%
 N/A
```

Comment: How the output should be for this  'data '?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect desired results.

Comment: What is wrong with the output that you're getting now?

Comment: I'm not getting "N/A" in my results for "-1.0000" and I'm unsure how to format the percentage in the case statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this code but something like this should work:

```
SELECT
case when CONVERT(FLOAT, sopm.TARGET_VALUE),  <= '-1'
    then   'N/A'
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(INT, sopm.TARGET_VALUE * 100)) + '%'
    END as TARGET_VALUE
FROM SUMMARY_PERFORMANCE_METRIC sopm
```

Or like this if you want decimal places in the percentage:

```
SELECT
case WHEN sopm.TARGET_VALUE  <= -1
    THEN   'N/A'
WHEN sopm.TARGET_VALUE  >= 1
THEN sopm.TARGET_VALUE
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), sopm.TARGET_VALUE * 100)) + '%'
    END as TARGET_VALUE
FROM SUMMARY_PERFORMANCE_METRIC sopm
```

I know you have probably finished with this but I just edited the second example of my answer to show how it could of handled the 3.5.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  Either answer could be considered correct but I elected to use cast instead of convert.  Was initially receiving a -206 invalid object error using convert.  Was not sure how to handle the exception when the result is >= 1  (3.5 instead of 350%).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, it will add the percentage sign for you in the case as well as formatting your percentage.

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN spom.TARGET_VALUE LIKE('-1.%') THEN 'N/A'
            ELSE STR(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), spom.TARGET_VALUE) * 100), 2, 0) + '%'
        END AS TARGET_VALUE
FROM    SUMMARY_PERFORMANCE_METRIC spom
```

Using this and some data as tests gave me this result...

```
TARGET_VALUE
N/A
40%
90%
```

Comment: But did you look at the example test data 3.5000 giving a result of 3.5, not 3500%